# Want to make variables using the same character name in for loop in r

Tags: r

I Want to make variables using character name in for loop.

For instance:

```
cultivar <- c("uri", "keumgang", "saeal", "ahnbaek")

for(i in cultivar){
    anova_height_i <- aov(plant_height ~ treatment, data = data_i)
}
```

From the above, I expect to have variables

```
anova_height_uri <- aov(plant_height ~ treatment, data = data_uri)
...
...
anova_height_ahnbaek <- aov(plant_height ~ treatment, data = data_ahnbaek)
```

But I got the error message:

> Error in aov(plant_height ~ treatment, data = data_i) : 
>     object 'data_i' not found

How could I get the results that I expect?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Fit several anovas using differeent datasets or simply get the dataset name?

Comment: I want to do anova with several datasets which have the same dataframe but different names.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `assign` and `get`:

```r
cultivar <- c("uri", "keumgang", "saeal", "ahnbaek")

for(i in cultivar){
  assign(
    paste0('anova_height_', i),
    aov(plant_height ~ treatment, data = get(paste0('data_', i)))
  )
}
```